# Opening Python IDE on Desktop

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to open the python IDE with a specific program open on my desktop (in the shell so that I can edit it).  The code I am using is:

```
 os.system("C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\idle.py C:/Python27/lib/file_name.py")
```

Its working, but its opening three things:

1. A command line (without the actual command line)

   An empty IDE

   The program I was trying to open

I dont want the previous two things to open, just the third.  Whats going on, how do I fix it?

Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 1):

The command window opening is an inherent part of os.system, something as simple as this should work:

```
C:\Python26\Lib\idlelib\idle.py "C:\file1.py"
```

This opens just the code you want in IDLE, without the shell. To run it in the IDLE shell (opening it in the process), simply press F5.

Comment: I actually want the program open in IDLE.

Comment: @NeilAggarwal That *does* open the program in IDLE. Do you mean that you want to open it *from* IDLE?

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I am not great with the vocab.  Here is what I want, ideally: I want just the code to open in IDLE so that I can edit it and nothing else.  If that isn't possible, I want as few additional things to open on my desktop as possible.

Comment: @NeilAggarwal That's exactly what the snippet I posted does. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/8UIhZut.png) is a screenshot showing the cmd window, and the IDLE window that opened from it. That's the only window that opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pythonw.exe` for this:

```
os.system('C:\Python27\pythonw.exe "<absolute path to your file here>"')
```